# Tooltip overlay problems when transform: matrix is used

Tags: css, tooltip

I am trying to integrate a tooltip into a generated HTML code.
My problem is that the tooltip will not cover lower elements defined in the HTML if transform: matrix is applied to them and I have to create a tooltip for the a word and display an image (in this example **Benzene**)
A basic example of my issue can be observer in this [CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jZQaGr)

CSS:

```
.normal {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: skyblue;
}

.changed {
  transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 80, 120);
  background-color: pink;
  position: absolute;
  unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
  transform-style:flat;
  z-index:900;
}
.hover {
    position:relative;
    background-color:#e6ffff;
    z-index:900;
}

.tooltip {
  top:0px;
  background-color:white;
  color:white;
  border-radius:5px;
  border:solid 1px #111111;
  display:none;
  position:absolute;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s;
  -moz-transition:  opacity 0.5s;
  -ms-transition: opacity 0.5s;
  -o-transition:  opacity 0.5s;
  transition:  opacity 0.5s;
  z-index:999;
}

.hover:hover .tooltip {
    display:inline;
    z-index:999;
}
.tooltip:hover{ z-index:999;}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="" style="width:100%;">
<span class="hover">Benzene
    <span class="tooltip">
      <img name="mol-img-786" style="width:200px; height:200px;" src="data:image/png;base64,..."/>
    </span>
</span>  is an important organic chemical compound with the chemical formula C6H6. The benzene molecule is composed of six carbon atoms joined in a ring with one hydrogen atom attached to each. As it contains only carbon and hydrogen atoms, benzene is classed as a hydrocarbon.
</div>
<div class="changed"><span class="hover">Benzene
    <span class="tooltip">
      <img name="mol-img-786" style="width:200px; height:200px;" src="data:image/png;base64,..."/>
    </span>
</span>  is an important organic</div><br/><br/><br/><br/>
<div class="changed"><span class="hover">Benzene
    <span class="tooltip">
      <img name="mol-img-786" style="width:200px; height:200px;" src="..."/>
    </span>
</span>   is an important organic</div><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
<div class="changed"><span class="hover">Benzene 
    <span class="tooltip">
      <img name="mol-img-786" style="width:200px; height:200px;z-index:999;" src="data:image/png;base64,..."/>
    </span>
</span>  is an important organic</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nu ai nevoie de z-index pe toate elementele.
Te intereseaza doar `div.changed`.

Avand in vedere ca tooltipul apare de la nivelul elementului in jos. Doar elementele urmatoare vor aparea deasupra tooltipului.
Daca primul `.changed` are `z-index: 1000`, urmatorul element are nevoie de `z-index: 999`, al treilea element are nevoie de `z-index: 998` etc. , pentru a fii tot timpu sub cel de deasupra lui.

Daca ai putine elemente, adauga z-index manual, dar daca elementele sunt generate poti folosii un `for loop` din js.

```
document.addEventListener('ready', function(){
   let changed = document.getElementsByClassName('changed'); (1)
   let index = 1000;
   for(let c=changed.length ; c > 0 ; c++){
   changed[c].zIndex = index; (2)
   index--;
   }
});
```

(1) Selectezi toate elementele cu clasa `.changed`.

(2) Elementul actual din loop va primii indexul actual

(3) Indexul este decrementat cu 1, astfel urmatorul element ce va intra in loop, va primii un z-index cu 1 mai mic.

Pentru o varianta mai eleganta, scrisa in js, zi intr-un comentariu.

TLDR: **Daca ai putine elemente, adauga z-index manual, dar daca elementele sunt generate poti folosii js din codeblock.**

Comment: I was afraid I have to do that manually .... I tried CSS way and it did not work, but the manual solution fixed my issue.
The code needs to go in ascending order of the elements with the class and assign a zIndex from high value to low, but your solution is the one that made it work ;)

Thanks!